# Redefining a Polymer element at run-time

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to change the definition of a Polymer element at run-time.  I have tried just reregistering the element, but get the error that a component with that name already exists.

Any help on how to redefine an element at trun time appreciated

Comment: If i not mistaken, in run time if you imported `<your-element>.html` you cannot change it definition. But you can manipulate it local DOM, properties and behaviour. Would you explain reason that you want to redefine?

Comment: I'm making an IDE for HTML and want to have live updates of the element without having to reload page and attain same state.

Answer (score 4):

To "manipulate the DOM, properties and behavior," as Sergey mentions, you can use the native `ready` callback as [described here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/registering-elements.html#ready-method).

```
<script>
  (function() {
    Polymer({
      is: 'example-element',
      properties: {...},
      ready: function() {
        // access a local DOM element by ID using this.$
        this.$.header.textContent = 'Hello!';
      }
    });
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: I'm trying to do more than change DOM, I want to redefine the everything about the element. I'm making an IDE for HTML and want to have live updates of the element without having to reload page and attain same state.

Comment: What do you mean `live updates`? Are you talking about single page application or something?

Comment: @SergeyChizhik: It's possible "live updates" refers to "data binding" and updating the DOM tree?

Comment: @Mowzer, yes maybe. But it's basics of `Polymer` and not related with  question about redefining

Comment: by "live updates" I mean adding an attribute or adding a method onto the prototype of the element, basically I want to rewrite the element at runtime.

Comment: Is it possible to completely removed the element from the document, then I could inject new definition?